# Shopify How can I add translate code in JS?

Tags: shopify, liquid

How can I add translate code to this js code snippet on my theme.js ?

```
s=function(){r.html('<div class="wishlist-empty-heading"><h2 class="theme_main_heading">Your wishlist is empty</h2><div class="alert alert-warning">'+theme.strings.wishlistNoResult+'</div><a href="/collections/all" class="theme_buttons">Return to shop</a></div>')};
```

There is the text "Your Wishlist is empty" I want to add my translation code here but how can I do it ?

if I add this I got javascript error:

```
<h2 class="theme_main_heading">' + {{ 'products.product.wishlist_text' | t }} + '</h2>
```

Comment: what error you got on adding this code, need more information about it